# Program to add a page number to a .djvu document

Tags: djvu

I am looking for a program that can:

- add page numbers to a .djvu document.

If possible:

- free
- supporting Windows 7
- allowing to choose the font/size/location of the page numbers. I don't want to have to convert the documents to PDF (I know how to [insert page numbers in a PDF document](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/979937))

Comment: For DJVU beyond version 2.0 you could have used DjVuer Pro. According to this it is not possible anymore http://www.djvu-soft.narod.ru/planetdjvu/adding_headers_footers_and_caption_text_to_djvu_files.htm